# Why spring client cannot obtain spring config server properties?

Tags: spring

I've got a `@SpringBootApplication`, running with the `production` profile, and a spring config server,

```
{"name":"config-client","profiles":["production"],"label":null,"version":"97611975e6ddb87c7213e18ddbe203ab6ae5485d","state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"http://git/scm/abm/abm-settings.git/application-production.yml","source":{"my.pretty.property.id":21}}]}
```

I cannot load property `my.pretty.property.id` from server (they are always null), I am using

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.pretty.property")
public class MyProperties {
    private String id;
}
```

and my bootstrap.yml is

```
spring.cloud:
  config:
    uri: http://${SERVICE_HOST}/${PROJECT_KEY}-config-server
    enabled: false
    failFast: true
```

build.gradle contains this:

```
"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-all",
"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-consul-core",
"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix",
"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard",
"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin",
"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client"
```

My client application is normally built and deployed, what am I missing?

Comment: Try changing the prefix to `source.my.pretty.property`

Comment: it didn't help unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following config is right, but spring.cloud.config.enabled should be true, I didn't overrride it in my production environment

Answer (score 3):

From [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.2.3.RELEASE/#_client_side_usage):

> The HTTP service has resources in the form:
>
> /{application}/{profile}[/{label}]
>   /{application}-{profile}.yml
>   /{label}/{application}-{profile}.yml
>   /{application}-{profile}.properties
>   /{label}/{application}-{profile}.properties

As you mentioned your application is running under `production` profile - hence Spring will try to find file: `<cloud-config-server-url>/application-production.yml` and load it, besides `application.properties`. But your properties are located in `application-integration.yml` and you don't use `integration` profile.

So the solution is to use an `integration` profile or to create an `application-production.yml` on your config. server.

Comment: fixed a misprint description, I've got an application-production.yml file too, thanks